# Cassandra 2.1.0 Out of Memory

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We have recently started playing with cassandra, and have setup a

4 Datacenter (DC1, DC2, DC3, DC4), (3 nodes per datacenter cluster running on VMs), memory, memtables, etc..configs are running at their defaults.

We have a cron job that runs on each node (approx 1 per week, staggered) to execute a repair jobs.

Anyways we had 4 nodes die all at the same time, (2 died in DC1, and 2 died in DC2 both dc1/dc2 are in the US, the other 2 are in the EU) all with Out of Memory, the stacks appear to be same on all 4 nodes..(see below for the full stack).

The nodes crashed on the weekend, and there should have been no client activity hitting the cluster at the time (as this is a test cluster), looking at the logs shows the only activities being repair/compaction.

Each node is running on a 4gb box, with heap set to 1gb.
The actual data load of the cluster at this point is negligible, we have 3 keyspaces (with RF=2 to all DataCenters) where each keyspace is aprox 2-12kb in size.. (the 12kb one is in fact OpsCenter which we just installed on Friday..could the install of OpsCenter be causing this?)

I suspect we have not pushed more then 20Mb in transactions into the system as of yet.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this OOM?
I took a brief look at the hprof dumps, but nothing really stood out.

We have done some more digging around, and have determined that our
nodetool repair operation is running for 12+ hours (with resulted in another node running nodetool repair as well at the same time, I believe the 2 repairs running at the same caused the nodes to OOM).

I have also been able to replicate OOM errors on demand by running a 1 nodetool repair job, and well as a nodetool compact keyspace operation.

I have no idea why it would be taking 12+ hours to run repair.

We have have also determined that some of our data directories/keyspace/table directories had over 7500+ files, perhaps this is causing the process to run forever.

also reading the 2.1 docs we have started playing with nodetool repair -par -inc
process is still running at the moment.

some thoughts:
We thinking maybe the best strategy for us is to run:

1. nodetool compact for each keyspace on node x.
2. nodetool -inc

then keep 'this script' running contiously, cycling throw all nodes in all datacenters 
(perhaps waiting a few hours between switching nodes).
does this sound reasonable? this will at least ensure only 1 repair job is running at time, and never at the same time a major compaction is running.

### Stack trace:

```
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-13] 2014-12-07 18:32:14,961 AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:167 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-13,5,main]: {}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.<init>(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.open(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:43) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.createReader(CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.PoolingSegmentedFile.getSegment(PoolingSegmentedFile.java:40) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getFileDataInput(SSTableReader.java:1694) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.IndexedSliceReader.setToRowStart(IndexedSliceReader.java:107) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.IndexedSliceReader.<init>(IndexedSliceReader.java:83) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.createReader(SSTableSliceIterator.java:65) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.<init>(SSTableSliceIterator.java:42) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(SliceQueryFilter.java:179) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(QueryFilter.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:284) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1872) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1680) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.getRow(Keyspace.java:345) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadVerbHandler.doVerb(ReadVerbHandler.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:163) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:103) [apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
```

Comment: I don't have any specific issues in mind, but I would recommend getting up to the latest 2.1 release before getting too deep on this.